# Create Centered Circles from Rectangles Images using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have images being passed dynamically to the UI and they can sent as any size size. I then need to scale them to specific sizes depending on which img tag that image is going to be displayed in. These images need to be circles of a statically set size, but not ovals and when they are cropped I want the circle to come from the center of my image.

I have created a circular image using boostrap's img-circle:

```
<img class="img-circle" src="image.jpg" width="117px" height="117px"/>
```

I have many of similar images of various sizes being layed out using:

```
<div class="row" style="margin: -40px 10px 30px">
```

This is working, except my images are ending up stretched to fit the circle rather than just cropping from it. Is there any simple way I can cause them to crop vs stretch?

I'm hoping I can do this just using my img tag, as using something with "background-image" seems to mess up my layout.

Added a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/jgt1qy7y/1/

Comment: Could you set up a fiddle?

Comment: I've added a fiddle. Its my first time creating one though, so please let me know if there are any problems with it.

Comment: What do you mean by ***"These images need to be circles "***, are the images not circles already? Are you looking for css border-radius?

Comment: [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/jgt1qy7y/10/) is the fiddle with corrected links to bootstrap css and js

Comment: You say using background images messes up your layout? Can you elaborate?

Comment: @DanWhite The images start as rectangles. If I simply try to round them with img-circle without setting the size they become ovals http://jsfiddle.net/oqpe8ppz/

If I could guarantee they were already squares this would work just fine, but I can't.

Comment: So just use the css rule border-radius as the answer @DannyVonHolten provided then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should enclose your image in a parent div.

The only thing .img-circle does is apply border-radius: 50%; It will inherit the width and the height of the chosen element. If those are not equal it will be an oval. In that case you will have to define sizes but then the images will get distorted. So that's why you need a parent div. To set the width and the height, and not distort the image.

```css
.img-circle {
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
    height: 117px;
    width: 117px;
    overflow: hidden;
   
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.img-circle.hor img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    width: auto;
    height: 117px;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
 }

.img-circle.vert img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 117px;
    height: auto;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
    <div class="img-circle hor">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
    </div>

    <div class="img-circle vert">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x350" />
    </div>
```

Comment: Nope!. The div isn't necessary with bootstrap

Comment: Well, it is if you want your images to be a fixed with and height, and they are not ... because that's the problem OP describes here. I'll make my snippet a bit better to show u

Comment: @choma - How is this relevant? Bootstrap is a helper, it doesn't extend CSS in any way. Just provides a set of pre-defined css rules.

Comment: @DanWhite, this answer says that a `div` is necessary, but if using bootstrap css, applying .img-circle to the `image` tag is enough to make it work.

Comment: But I'm not really sure about the image strength :-/ Maybe @DannyvanHolten has the reason.

Comment: @Choma, the only thing .img-circle does is apply border-radius: 50%; It will inherit the width and the height of the chosen element. If those are not equal it will be an oval (which is the OP's problem). In that case you will have to define sizes (which again is OP's problem, because the images will get distorted.)

So that's why you need a parent div. To set the width and the height, and not distort the image. So it is not necessary to have a parent div, but in this case it is.

Comment: @DannyvanHolten +1 :) (you should add that comment to the answer)

Comment: This appears to be solving most of my problems, however why do you need to have a hor and vert class? Can they be combined into one class as I don't know which direction the images need to be translated due to them being set dynamically.

Comment: @Fozefy I reckoned this would be the problem, so I made two examples. You can off-course do this automatically. Unfortunately (in my knowledge) this is not possible in pure CSS, and you would need Javascript for that. With javascript you can detect what the scape of the image is. But maybe even better is to make thumbnails of uploaded images with an image library (GD Image Library for example) and make those thumbnails square. WordPress doet this pretty good for example. But this is a lot harder.

Comment: P.S: The third solution is to use background images with background-size: cover instead of images. But that would be wrong when you view it semantically.

Comment: @DannyvanHolten I'm already passing the (local) URL to the image using AngularJS. I'm assuming its likely going to just be easier to crop the image there and then just pass that image to the UI instead of the original?

Comment: I don't know if this would be easier. I don't really know much about AngularJS. But it is for certain better (keeping performance in mind).

Answer (score 1):

Right, as far as I can answer from the information you've provided, you're setting the image tag to have 117px in both height and width. This is the IMG tag you're changing, and so every image will be stretched TO that specification.

So, you have two options:
1) You can either set a specific width or height and allow the circle to be auto width or height, e.g

```
.img-circle{
  width:auto;
  height:auto;
  width:117px;
  max-height:117px;
}
```

On this I have set a max height of 117px so that HUGE long ones don't go overboard, but this will make them tiny in the circle http://jsfiddle.net/jgt1qy7y/8/

Or, secondly, you could create a DIV with fixed width 117px by 117px (I'm assuming you're using this as profile pictures or something?), then dynamically modify the style of the DIV to add a background image then configure that in your CSS:

```
.img-circle{
    width:117px;
    height:117px;
}
```

For your div. Then, you can dynamically output the URL of the image into your STYLE of the div

```
<div class="img-circle" style="background-image:url('echo your url here');"></div>
```

You can then style the background image by adding CSS to your .img-circle:

```
.img-circle{
  background-size:contain/cover;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  backgrund-position:50% 50%;
}
```

You'll have to check out cropping an image in javascript if you want the image to fit exactly how you want it, but you get the jist.

Disclaimer: I've never properly learned CSS from websites, I've picked it up as I've gone along... Sorry if this is written badly!

Comment: Oh it looks like the commenter above be summed it up real faster than I did, sorry!